# how to change the SharePoint folders image dynamically with different image in SharePoint

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I want to change the default icon (Yellow Thumbnail) of the Image library folder with one of the image resides in every folder dynamically.
Each folder contains 10-12 images, I want to put anyone of the image as a thumbnail for the folder.

Comment: Now this is an intriguing idea. There should a way to do this using some weird JSLink magic, but I wonder how one could get the data about the picture... maybe having the link to the current image as an hidden field on the folder CT and keeping it updated via an event receiver? Anyway, have my vote